# Signed integer in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a=6;
    int b=-20;
    (a+b>6)?puts(">6"):puts("<=6");
    return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs `>6`. But I got a doubt. `b=-20` will hold a negative value (`-18`) 
after doing the 2's complement as it's a signed integer. So it should output `<=6` but its 
giving an output as `>6`.

Comment: Note that using `?:` to conditionally call functions is considered bad practice.

Comment: @Iron: Because ?: is an operator, the statement is an *expression* and has a value (being discared here).  It is not equavalent to if-else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the C99 standard, section 6.3.1.8 ("Usual arithmetic conversions"):

> if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand
>   with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type.

Basically, in the case of your example code, `unsigned int` and `int` have the same rank, so it's equivalent to:

```
(a + (unsigned int)b > 6)
```

To fix it, you need to explicitly cast in the other direction, i.e.:

```
((int)a + b > 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to be found in section "6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions" of the C99 standard, which favors the unsigned type when a signed type and an unsigned one are passed to a binary operator (the reality is much more subtle than that).

See [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/04/11/Promotion-rules) for another example of working through the rules in 6.3.1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing signed and unsigned integers in your code.  That is a **bad thing**.  Try the following snippet:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0;
    int b=-20;
    printf("(a + b) = %f", (a + b));
    return 0;
}
```

Don't mix signed and unsigned integers because the compiler will do a silent conversion just when you don't want it to.